# ASP.Net MVC: How to force user to select any checkbox by data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have showing many `checkboxes` for hobbies property in view model but i like to attach `ValidationMessageFor` as a result user should be force to select any one checkbox out of many.

### so here is model & viewmodel

```
public class Hobby
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class SampleViewModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select any Hobbies")]
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

### action method code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var SampleVM = new SampleViewModel();
    SampleVM.Products = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product{ ID=1, Name="IPhone" },
        new Product{ ID=2, Name="MacBook Pro" },
        new Product{ ID=3, Name="iPod" }           
    };

    SampleVM.Hobbies = new List<Hobby>()
    {
        new Hobby(){ Name = "Reading", IsSelected= false },
        new Hobby(){ Name = "Sports" ,IsSelected= false},
        new Hobby(){ Name = "Movies" ,IsSelected= false}
    };
    return View(SampleVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel vm)
{
    ViewBag.IsPostBack = false;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Product p = vm.Products.Where(x => x.ID == vm.SelectedProductId).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.IsPostBack = true;
        ViewBag.ProductID = p.ID.ToString();
        ViewBag.ProductName = p.Name.ToString();
        return View(vm);
    }
    else
    {
        var SampleVM = new SampleViewModel();
        SampleVM.Products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product{ ID=1, Name="IPhone" },
            new Product{ ID=2, Name="MacBook Pro" },
            new Product{ ID=3, Name="iPod" }           
        };
        SampleVM.Hobbies = new List<Hobby>()
        {
            new Hobby(){ Name = "Reading", IsSelected= false },
            new Hobby(){ Name = "Sports" ,IsSelected= true},
            new Hobby(){ Name = "Movies" ,IsSelected= true}
        };

        return View(SampleVM);
    }
```

### view code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <b>Hobbies</b><br />
        @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Hobbies.Count(); x++)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected) @: &nbsp; 
            @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected, Model.Hobbies[x].Name) @: &nbsp;
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hobbies, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

so tell me what to change in code as a result validation message will fire if user select no check boxes for hobbies.

thanks

Comment: bit close to my requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491772/mvc-3-custom-validation-attribute-for-multiple-checkboxes    http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/validation-of-required-checkbox-in-asp-net-mvc/       http://criticaldevelopers.com/post/2015/03/18/check-atleast-one-checkbox-from-multiple-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-or-validate-checkboxlist-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: http://benfoster.io/blog/checkbox-lists-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: You need to write your own custom `ValidationAttribute` (but this will work server side only, - its not possible to get client side validation for a collection using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you could have discuss with sample code. anyway i will try and let u know. thanks